# Solr 4.3.1 dataimport issue

Tags: oracle, solr, weblogic-10.x

Hi I was previously using Solr 3.6 on weblogic server. It was working fine. Now I have upgraded to Solr 4.3.1. I have configured everything. But I am seeing issue with dataimport.  I am getting 'Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: java.sql.SQLException: Result set already closed' and 'SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(),​ indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!' Any help is appreciated. I am indexing from Oracle DB.   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6934525/326543) help you?

Comment: Thanks Srikanth but i dont have any nested entities, still would try to add 'rootEntity' and see.

Comment: Tried adding rootEntity also. No luck.